# Unsigned short int to Binary in C without using malloc() function?

Tags: c, type-conversion, bit, unsigned-integer

I wrote a program that changes an unsigned int to into binary. In my function I use the malloc() function. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without the malloc().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *toBinary(unsigned n);

int main(void) {
     int n;

     printf("Enter an integer to convert: ");
     scanf("%d",&n);

     char* binary = toBinary(n); 

     printf("%s",binary);

     return 0;
} 


char* toBinary(unsigned n) {
     char* binary = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
     int j = 0;
     unsigned i;
     for (i = 1 << 16; i > 0; i = i / 2) {
             if(j == 8)
                   binary[j++] = ' ';
             else
                   binary[j++] = (n & i) ? '1' : '0'; 
     }
    binary[j]='\0';
    return binary;
}
~
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, Declare the `binary` array in `main` like: `char binary[33]` (33 because you probably need 32 bytes + plus a null terminator), and pass `binary` as a second argument to `toBinary`.

Comment: There's no mention of `short` in the code, though the hard-coded `16` might be a reference to `sizeof(short)`.  Interestingly, the `sizeof(char)` is identical to `1`, and is modestly pointless — so you both over-used and under-used the `sizeof` operator.  Additionally, you are not allocating enough space; you need to add a byte to the memory allocation to allow for the null byte — or for the space you add in the output.

Comment: Side note: If you already initialise with `i = 1 << 16` I'd really prefer `i >>= 1` in post loop operation, though both are equivalent.

Comment: Oh, you're `malloc`'ed array is too short by two, as you add a space in between and null-terminate the string!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple: Pass the pre-allocated buffer to the function:

```
typedef enum
{
    CE_NoError,
    CE_InsufficientMemory,
} ConversionError;

ConversionError toBinary(unsigned int n, size_t length, char binary[length])
{
   // check first if length suffices to hold all characters
   // plus the terminating null character

   // use the array passed to instead of the one malloc'ed one...
}
```

Usage:

```
char binary[sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT + /*1*/ 2]; // (!): intermediate space!
if(toBinary(theValue, sizeof(binary), binary) != CE_NoError)
{
    // appropriate error handling!
}
```

Instead of the enum you might return `bool` (need to include `stdbool.h` for) if you consider the enum overkill for just one single error type...

Side note: Replace `unsigned int` (as coming from your code) with `unsigned short` if if you indeed want to convert the latter as in your title (and as your for loop indicates).

Comment: `unsigned short` -> `unsigned int`. `unsigned n` is equivalent to `unsigned int n`

Comment: In modern style, you'd do better with `int toBinary(unsigned n, size_t length, char binary[length]) { … }` where the key change is in the argument list (specify size first and then use it in the array declaration), and the secondary change is to return `int` status so that if the buffer is too small, you can report the error.  Classically, return 0 if all is OK and some other, probably negative, value on failure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The "0 is OK" rule of thumb actually is more true for the exit status of programs than the return values of functions in C.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica — it does depend on where you look. Unix system calls that don’t have other information to return return 0 on success and -1 on failure.  POSIX Pthreads returns 0 on success and a (positive) error number on failure.  The software I work with mostly uses 0 for success and (mostly) negative on failure. There are counter-examples:  IIRC, OpenSSL returns 0 on failure. You pays your money and takes your pick. I prefer the zero on success variant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Exactly -- many functions return something. Programs can "return" a result as output (grep etc.) and in addition provide a diagnostic exit code; functions often aren't designed for that (although the paradigm of `bool tryXY(some_arg, some result_ref) seems to become more common, especially for C# and Java because it saves an alloc/free pair. But then "OK" is 1 ;-) ) The bool return (or equivalent) often leads to elegant style, like (while(cin >> i)).